# My Laptop isn't getting powered on. Surprisingly, it works after exposure to sunlight for about 5 mins, every day. What might be the issue?

Tags: boot, graphics-card, cpu, motherboard, ics

My HP Laptop(Model: 15-bs146TU), is not getting powered on. Surprisingly, when I expose it to very low intense sunlight for about 5-10 minutes, it gets turned on and works perfectly fine for the whole day. But the very next day, again the same problem is getting repeated. Also, every time I power on, the system's date & time is getting changed. Seeking support from anyone who has encountered such cases or experts, what might be the issue? Thanks for considering my request.

Comment: Cmos battery is dead. Replace it.

Comment: Your test vector description is very complex leaving many options for problems, risks or mistake. I would go to your local Geek Squad and discuss this taking good notes, with an agent to properly identify & tackle your issues. Without an IT expert face-to-face for you this doesn’t get closed cleanly (battery does sound suspect)

Comment: Is the behavior same with, when on Battery and when on Mains power?

Comment: @Mokubai CMOS has absolutely nothing to do with the sunlight. You should state what he wrote that leads you to the conclusion about the CMOS (e.g. date and time)

Comment: If it's CMOS battery, then from what I recall, the time/date might slow, so be behind.. or maybe reset to a particular date/time. Do you see either of those?  No idea re the sunlight.

Comment: If I were you i'd demonstrate that to an electrician or laptop repair shop, the computer turning on in the sunlight.. it's so interesting I doubt they'd charge. Can you recreate that with a lamp? Does it turn on automatically without you pushing the button? And just in the light? So incredibly strange. You should make a youtube video about it. What you describe is about as rare as  a UFO. I've seen a UFO twice(one time one type, one time anoter type, and both times with a witness), but i've not seen what you are describing.. get it on video.

Comment: @barlop "every time I power on, the system's date & time is getting changed" strongly indicates a dead CMOS battery, and it needing to be out in sunlight suggests that the battery being warm is helping the chemical reaction slightly to let it just work just enough. I've seen systems in the past refuse to boot with a dead CMOS.

Comment: If this is a newer laptop that doesn't have a CMOS battery then this is a sign that the main system battery connection is suspect, or the battery itself is failing. If the battery is removable then look for dirt or damage to the connectors. Warmth can cause metals and plastics to expand slightly and shift and make better contact. If everything looks fine then you should probably take it to a repair shop to check the battery connections.